# crear mi propio tipo de archivo y su ejecutable

Tags: archivo, batch

cree mi tipo de archivo llamado **me** y me guntaria crear csu ejecutable al hacer click me abra la aplicacion pero solo tengo expriencia con batch. y me preguntaba ¿es posible crear una aplicacion que ejecute el tipo de archivos **me**. o existe otro lenguaje que deberia aprender?

> al hacer click en archivos **me** me ejecute mi programa

> --------archivo **me**--------

```
  echo "hola";
```

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de Windows; los [**archivos asociados**](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/2512137) a un programa se hacen mediante la extensión. Desde luego, al momento de instalar el programa (el ejecutable -**.exe**-) en el instalador se especifica realizar esa asociación (si el [*instalador*](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/crear-instalador-vs10-installshield.html) y/o versión lo permite; esta características puede no estar presente de una versión a otra e incluso no existir de forma general en el generador de instalador).

El contenido del archivo (en el "caso" que mencionas tu **me**) ya sea contenga *texto plano* o este en *binario* (estructura) deberá ser leída por tu programa e ir ejecutando cada instrucción que le coloques. Esto desde luego tú lo defines según tu necesidad.